# Postgresql - Group By

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, grafana

I have a simple groupby scenario. Below is the output of the query.

[image]

Query is:
`select target_date, type, count(*) from table_name group by target_date, type`

The query and output is perfectly good.
My problem is I am using this in Grafana for plotting. That is Grafana with postgres as backend.
What happens is since "type2" category is missed on 01-10-2020 and 03-10-2020, type2 category never gets plotted (side to side bar plot) at all. Though "type2" is present in other days.

It is expecting some thing like

[image]

So whenever a category is missed in a date, we need a count with 0 value.
Need to handle this in query, as the source data cannot be modified.
Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE t3.weekday = 'N'` turns your outer join into an inner join, because in outer-joined rows the `t3.weekday` is null. Change this to `AND t3.weekday = 'N'` to make it part of the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a list of all the `target_date/type` combinations. That can be done with a `CROSS JOIN` of two `DISTINCT` selects of `target_date` and `type`. This list can be`LEFT JOIN`ed to `table_name` to get counts for each combination:

```
SELECT dates.target_date, types.type, COUNT(t.target_date)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT target_date
  FROM table_name
) dates
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT type
  FROM table_name
) types
LEFT JOIN table_name t ON t.target_date = dates.target_date AND t.type = types.type
GROUP BY dates.target_date, types.type
ORDER BY dates.target_date, types.type
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0654d61e9bfc0c0ea298530af86402dd)

Comment: That really helped. Suppose I want to add a condition check on my  left joined table i.e table_name where weekday="N"  [select target_date, type, count(*) from table_name group by target_date, type where weekday="N" ] I tried adding it, after the join but the result was wrong. Any help here?

Comment: You would need `t.weekday = 'N'` note you need a table alias and also you should use single quotes, not double around `n`

Comment: Ya I did that. Updated the question with the query I used for this. But the result was missing the categories like before.

Comment: @Learner You need to add the condition `t.weekday = 'N'` to the `ON` clause of the final left join in Nick's query.  The problem here is that if you put the restriction on `weekday` into a `WHERE` clause you might drop some records you want to keep.

Comment: @Learner as Tim said, just change `LEFT JOIN table_name t ON t.target_date = dates.target_date AND t.type = types.type` to `LEFT JOIN table_name t ON t.target_date = dates.target_date AND t.type = types.type AND t.weekday = 'N'` and that should give you the results you want.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a calendar table approach here:

```
SELECT
    t1.target_date,
    t2.type,
    COUNT(t3.target_date) AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT target_date FROM yourTable) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM yourTable) t2
LEFT JOIN yourTable t3
    ON t3.target_date = t1.target_date AND
       t3.type = t2.type
GROUP BY
    t1.target_date,
    t2.type
ORDER BY
    t1.target_date,
    t2.type;
```

The idea here is to cross join subqueries finding all distinct target dates and types, to generate a starting point for the query.  Then, we left join this intermediate table to your actual table, and find the counts for each date and type.

Comment: Modified the question with adding conditions. Have given the query that I used and corresponding output. Can you help on how to add extra conditions to the left joined or the main table?

Comment: ...and I have rolled back your question.  Just move that `WHERE` criteria to the `ON` clause of the last join.  Please don't change your question after many people have already answered it.  This is not how Stack Overflow's format works.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.target_date, tmp.type, sum(case when t.type = tmp.type then 1 else 0 end) 
from your_table t
cross join (select distinct type from your_table) tmp
group by t.target_date, tmp.type
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bcd9da/3)